# Laravel 4.2 - Trabalhando com tarefas assíncronas para gerar relatórios .xlsx

Tags: laravel-4, multithreading, assincronismo

Olá,
estou trabalhando com uma aplicação em Laravel 4.2 e preciso que, quando o usuário efetue a requisição para gerar um relatório do sistema, uma tarefa seja lançada para gerar o relatório, quando este relatório estiver pronto em uma pasta, preciso enviar um e-mail para o usuário com a URL para efetuar o download do relatório.

Existe uma forma de trabalhar com tarefas assíncronas no Laravel? Algum exemplo?

Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução para suprir minhas necessidades, um aplicativo gerenciador de filas chamado Beanstalkd, consumir esse serviço é realmente fácil no Laravel 4.2, pois o mesmo possui suporte para utiliza-lo. Mais interessante ainda é saber que existem diversas bibliotecas em diversas linguagens (C/C++, Django, Go, Java, PHP, Lua, Python, entre outras) para utilizar o Beanstalkd.

**

### Instalação do Beanstalkd

**

A instalação pode ser feita em diversas versões do Linux, cito o Ubuntu, utilizando o gerenciador de pacotes apt-get, fácil de utilizar, o [website](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/download.html) possui informação de instalação para vários Sistemas Operacionais, para instalar só utilizar a linha de comando:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Para atualizar a lista do gerenciador de pacotes, e então:

```
sudo apt-get install beanstalkd
```

Para instalar o Beanstalkd, para iniciar o serviço utilize o comando:

```
sudo service beanstalkd start
```

**

### Instalação do Beanstalkd Console

**

Para poder ver o conteúdo das filas no Beanstalkd eu recomendo o Beanstalkd Console, simples de instalar facilita e muito verificar as filas do Beanstalkd e até encerrar processos que estejam travados nas filas, para instalar é fácil, basta baixar  o [arquivo do website oficial](https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console/archive/master.zip), descompactar e configurar no seu ambiente como um website. O acesso local se dá por *localhost:8080* (porta varia de acordo com a configuração do seu ambiente).

**

### Configuração do Laravel 4.2

**

Para consumir o serviço no Laravel 4.2:

Primeiramente adicione a dependência no projeto utilizando o Composer:

```
composer require pda/pheanstalk ~2.0
```

Em seguida, já com a base de dados configurada no Laravel, adicione uma tabela na base para receber erros de execução da fila com os comandos:

```
php artisan queue:failed-table

php artisan migrate
```

Deve-se então configurar o arquivo em **app/config/queue.php**, as seguintes linhas tem que ser alteradas:

```
'default' => 'beanstalkd', // Driver a ser utilizado, linha 18

'host'   => 'minhaFila', // Nome do host da sua fila, linha 39

'queue'  => 'projeto', // Nome da fila do seu projeto, linha 40
```

Com isso o Laravel 4.2 esta configurado e pronto para utilização. Para que o Laravel possa "escutar" a fila e atender suas requisições, na linha de comando, dentro da pasta da sua aplicação Laravel utilize o comando:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

**

### Exemplo

**

Como exemplo de teste, em uma versão "limpa" do Laravel já devidamente configurado para utilizar o Beanstalkd, proceda da seguinte forma:

**1.** Altere **/app/routes.php** para:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
```

**2.** Altere **/app/controllers/HomeController.php** para:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function showWelcome()
    {
        $numero = 120;
        // envia tarefa para fila
        Queue::push('Calculos@fatorial', array('numero' => $numero));

        return View::make('hello');
    }

}
```

**3.** Crie um arquivo com nome **Calculos.php** em **/app/controllers**, com o seguinte código:

```
<?php

    class Calculos {
        public function fatorial($job, $data)
        {
            Log::info('Iniciando JOB Fatorial');
            $valor = $data['numero'];
            Log::info('Valor obtido para Fatorial, iniciando calculos...');

            $r = 1;
            $fatorial = 0;

            // CALCULANDO
            for($i = $valor; $i > 0; $i--) {
                $r = $r * $i;
            }
            $fatorial = $r;
            Log::info('O fatorial obtido foi: ' . $fatorial);

            // Após execução da Job remove-la da lista
            $job->delete();

            Log::info('JOB Fatorial removida da Lista');
        }
    }
```

Agora basta rodar o seu ambiente e no navegador digitar a URL de acesso, cada vez que for atualizada a página, uma nova tarefa será lançada na lista do Beanstalkd, você pode visualizar as tarefas e até removê-las da lista utilizando o Beanstalkd Console. Lembre-se de utilizar o comando:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Dentro do diretório raiz do seu projeto Laravel para que o mesmo possa receber requisições da Lista do Beanstalkd.

Conclusão

No meu caso o Beanstalkd foi uma ótima solução para que a minha aplicação web fosse capaz de executar tarefas que exigem longo tempo de execução sem impactar a navegação dos clientes então, resolvi gastar um tempinho para escrever um pouco do conhecimento que obtive porque não foi fácil, espero que o conteúdo acima seja de grande ajuda.

Abraço.